# Replace dataframe values with data from other dataframe that match

Tags: python, pandas

I've a df1 that looks like (original one has over 1k rows):

```
   Invoice  Legal
0  153136   Quatro
1  202169   Rock
2  202129   Osiem
3  202119   Yetc
```

and a df2 that looks like:

```
   Legal    Org
0  Quatro   Sample
1  Osiem    Petra
```

I need to replace the column df1 Legal column with df2 Org data if the df2 Legal data is a match.

In this case would be (output):

```
   Invoice  Legal
0  153136   Sample -> changed
1  202169   Rock
2  202129   Petra  -> changed
3  202119   Yetc
```

I've tried the following, but I am getting an error. Thanks.

```
legal_dict = df2.set_index('Legal').to_dict()
df1['Legal'] = df1['Legal'].apply(lambda x: legal_dict[x])
```

Maybe worth to mention that the dfs are created via pd.read_csv

Comment: `df1.Legal=df1.Legal.map(df2.set_index('Legal')['Org']).fillna(df1.Legal)`

Comment: doesnt work, getting same error as below:   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Legal'

Comment: that is a keyerror which means there is no columns named `Legal` , please check what is the column name in the original data in df1. also check if there are preceeding or succeeding spaces if it exists